# missing rows report builder 2016

Tags: reporting-services

When i run a report in Report Builder 2016 or SSRS 2016 i have missing rows of data within a table. In Design if i change the font size of all the tables textboxes to 11pt instead of 10pt and then run the report all the rows appear. It also seems that if i change any font property that also fixes the issue. This is an inconsistent problem and seems to occur in no particular pattern. The 2 attached images show before any changes and after font size change.
Can anyone offer any ideas why this is occurring?

Report without any changes

[image]

Report with font size changed to 11pt

[image: font size changed]

Comment: Assuming this is a straightforward table that you've done nothing else to (ie: added groupings, aggregates, etc), this sounds like you may have found a bug in SSRS, probably best to report to Microsoft

Comment: Purely for my curiosity, it would be interesting if you could post your .RDL and include the data in your dataset query and by this I mean create the data structure and populate the table in the actual dataset query something like.`DECLARE @t TABLE(FilmName varchar(100), OscarWins int, RunTime int)` `INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('Jurassic Park', 3, 127), ('Spider-Man', 0, 121)` `SELECT * FROM @t`